# Find $3$ numbers whose product is $27$ and whose sum is minimal

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Find $3$ numbers whose product is $27$ and whose sum is minimal

I'm thinking one might have to use langrange multipliers. The answer is $(3,3,3)$, I am not sure how to get there though.

Comment: You might want to restrict to positive numbers, otherwise take $-n$, $-\frac{1}{n}$, and $27$, and you can make the sum as small as you like.

Comment: Can the numbers chosen be negative? Furthermore, are we limited to take only integers?

Comment: If the numbers are positive then, since their geometric mean is $3$, their arithmetic mean is at least $3$, so their sum is at least $9$, with equality only if they are all equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assume the numbers are $x$,$y$,$z$

the product equation is
$$xyz=27$$
the equation of sum is
$$S=x+y+z$$

$$S=x+y+27/(xy)$$
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial x}(x+y+\frac{27}{xy})=1-\frac{27}{yx^2}=0$$
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial y}(x+y+\frac{27}{xy})=1-\frac{27}{y^2x}=0$$

from the first equation 
$$yx^2-27=0$$
$$y=\frac{27}{x^2}$$

substitute $y$ in second equation to get $x=3$

Comment: Can you solve the tow equations for me so I can see the arithmetic?

Comment: @Tarrrr, the solving ok?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the numbers are positive reals, we can simply make use of AM-GM inequality.

$$\frac{a+b+c}{3}\geq (abc)^{1/3}\implies a+b+c\geq 3\times (27)^{1/3}=9$$

Equality holds when all the variables are equal, i.e., at $a=b=c=3$

Comment: You shouldn't assume they are positive reals when it's not mentioned!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the numbers $x,y,z$ are positive, by the AM-GM inequality, we have

$$\frac{x+y+z}{3}\ge\sqrt[3]{xyz}=3$$

Hence $x+y+z\ge9$ with equality iff $x=y=z$, hence $x=y=z=3$.